# Rebuild and ReRun a DockerContainer

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I'm experimenting with Docker, and I set up a Node App.
The App is in a GIT Repo in my Gogs Container.

I want to keep all the code inside my container, so at the app root I have my Dockerfile.

I want to create a Shell script to automatically ReBuild my Container and ReRun it.
This script is calling later through a "webhook-container" during a GIT push.

The Docker CLI has only a build and a run command. But both fails if a image or a container with the name already exists.

What is the best practice to handle this?

Remark: I don't want to keep my app sources on the host and update only the source and restart the container! 
I like the idea that my entire app is a container.

Comment: When you build an image with an existing name, it will replace the existing:latest image, don't know why your build fails. For container, yes you need to remove the old one, just `docker rm container_name/id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove docker containers and images before running build or run commands.

to remove all containers:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

to remove all images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

to remove a specific container:

```
docker rm -f containerName
```

then after executing the relevant commands above, then run your script. your script will typically build, run or pull as required.

Comment: Sounds good!
Is this a common practice to deploy the source (or binary) files within the container?

In the most samples the application is located at the host and is mounted in the container.

I found the Gogs container and it is awsome. You have tu pull the image and are only a "docker run" away from your selfhosted github.

No file permissions, no compilation and executable deployments needed.

Comment: most people build an image and push it to docker hub - you can then docker pull that image from anywhere - people tend to make their Dockerfiles available on docker hub for people to see but you do not need to access the original docker file when just pulling an image